# Calling the id of a div where the id looks like id=@something

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
<div class="external-event bg-red-gradient text-center" style="position: relative;">
                            <div id="@wo.id" class="WoOrders">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => wo.id) --
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => wo.warehouse_number) --
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => wo.warehouse_order_number) --
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => wo.warehouse_process_type) --
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => qu.QueueId)
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

How could i call the id of that div-element (i've tried getElementById() without success).

Thanks in advance.

(Newbie :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *server-side* code in ASP.NET:

```
@wo.id
```

It's not what gets rendered to the actual client-side.  That would be whatever the *value* of `wo.id` is.  So, for example, if the value is `"someIdentifier"` then you'd have this:

```
<div id="someIdentifier" class="WoOrders">
```

In which case you'd identify that element in JavaScript with:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someIdentifier');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the @ symbol with '\@wo.id' in your call.

https://jsfiddle.net/mw864znm/

```
document.getElementById('\@test').className= "red";
```